# English word for taking a derogatory term and owning it with pride

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, pejorative-language

E.g. "geek" or "queer" were originally meant as an insulting term, but were taken by the recipients as titles of pride.

Is there a term for this phenomenon?

Comment: Great question. There are many instances of this... impressionist, know-nothing, Yankee, tree-hugger, redneck, Obamacare, pimp... These terms deserve a grouping.

Comment: The most famous one is probably Christian, originally used as an insult meaning "little Christs".

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but the Dutch word is *geuzennaam* (:

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a word to describe an offensive term reclaimed by the offended group](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96880/is-there-a-word-to-describe-an-offensive-term-reclaimed-by-the-offended-group). Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93459/a-word-like-engooden/93494 .

Comment: The OP is not allowed to create tags, and "title" was the only one I could find.

Comment: Admittedly there aren't that many that fits the question but here are a few (possible) tags—"meaning", "single-word-request", "expressions", "offensive-language" and "terminology". The limit is five tags. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for looking those up; I've used a few

"terminology"? It fits, but it likely fits half of all requests on this board.

Comment: I think "terminology" might possibly be best because it's asking for a word about words. I personally hate "single word requests" because there could be a perfect term that consists of two words.

Comment: "Mudblood" isn't considered offensive by us muggle-borns any more. ;)

Comment: @foxyfennec, I'm pretty sure that *Christian* doesn't derive from an insult.

Comment: I don't think any of the answers here are correct. I doubt a word for this exists. The fact is that the meaning of the word does not change at all in these situations. The person using the word just accepts that this is how they are seen to others and goes with it. This generally happens with ALL derogatory terms; meaning that it is an inherent property of a derogatory term and not a special case. Michael Owen Sartins' answer is a possible exception but it is equally ambiguous in the end. When Israel brought back the dead Hebrew language, I would say that was true 'linguistic reclamation'.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[***Reappropriation***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation)
is the word you are looking for.

> ... the cultural process by which a group reclaims— **re-appropriates** —terms
>   or artifacts that were previously used in a way disparaging of that
>   group. For example, since the early 1970s, much terminology
>   referring to homosexuality—such as gay and (to a lesser extent) queer
>   and poof—has been reappropriated. [...] A **reclaimed** or **reappropriated** word is a word **that was at one time a pejorative but has been brought back into acceptable usage**—usually starting within the communities that experienced oppression under that word, but sometimes also among the general populace as well. [...]
>   This can have wider implications in the fields of discourse, and has been described in terms of personal or socio political empowerment. 
>   [...]
>
> **Politics**
>
> However, the phenomenon is much older, especially in politics
>   and religion. Cavalier is example of a derogatory nickname
>   reappropriated as self-identification, while Roundhead, a Royalists
>   derisory term for the supporters of the Parliamentary cause, is not
>   (it was a punishable offence in the New Model Army to call a fellow
>   soldier a roundhead). Tory (orig. from Middle Irish word for
>   'pursued man' Tóraidhe ), Whig (from 'whiggamore' (See the Whiggamore
>   Raid)) and 'Suffragette' are other British examples. Yankee was
>   originally used as an insult to America, but was reclaimed in the song
>   "Yankee Doodle".

Comment: I appreciate the historical context that Mari-Lou A applies to this question.  It is certainly better than what Michael Owen Sartin wrote.

Comment: More often, I've heard people say they're [“taking it back”](http://blackbot.blogspot.com/2011/05/what-african-americans-should-be-taking.html) – although “take back” is essentially what _reappropriate_ means!

Comment: Interesting, the Wikipedia article for 'pejorative' states the word is 'amelioration'.

Comment: "amelioration" brings to mind tending to bruises rather than taking the stick

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin - I actually think that what Michael Own Sartin wrote was more accurate and appropriate (if not necessarily *better* as such).  "Reclaim" is far preferable to "reappropriate", to my mind (in fact, I'm not even sure that the latter is a real word -- it's not in the OED or Websters').

Comment: But "reclaim" implies that one claimed it in the first place; more of an aikido Tachi dori

Comment: @simon It's on wikipedia, that should be good enough: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation :p

Comment: That's the one, M-L A. :-)

Comment: "Methodist" originated as a derogatory term too.

Answer (score 21):

The phrase "linguistic reclamation" has been used by academics.  See "A Queer Revolution: Reconceptualizing the Debate over Linguistic Reclamation" in *Colorado Research in Linguistics*.  http://www.colorado.edu/ling/CRIL/Volume17_Issue1/paper_BRONTSEMA.pdf

Comment: Interesting paper, especially the history behind "queer".

Answer (score 20):

[*Co-opt*](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=co-opt) is the common word for appropriating a derogatory term, especially in sense 3 of the linked definition:

> To take or assume for one's own use; appropriate: *co-opted the
>   criticism by embracing it.*

Comment: *[Co-opt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-opt)* is the usual word for  “To commandeer, appropriate or take over” (and also for  “To absorb or assimilate into an established group”) but that doesn't make it  the usual word for appropriating a derogatory term, merely *a* word for that.

Comment: @jwpat7 _Co-opt_ is the word I most often see used in print in this context.

Comment: +1 from me because I've actually heard this used in this way before, unlike the current top answer's "reappropriation" - which I've never heard in this context before.  Probably, that's just too technical for everyday speech, while "co-opt" is short and to the point.

Comment: Beyond not being specific to connotation-shifting usage, "Co-opt" if anything implies MISappropriation. Reappropriation or reclamation is always positive, so this is a bad fit.

And yes, I'm saying that the dictionary's example is bad.

As for "reappropriation" being too technical, I refer you to its use in an episode of 30 Rock:
http://www.30rockquotes.net/seasons/Season_5/30rockquotes_tgs_hates_women.cfm?quote=11833

Comment: Googling "[co-opt slur](https://www.google.com/search?source=ig&rlz=&q=co-opt+slur&oq=co-opt+slur&gs_l=igoogle.3...1255.4150.0.4616.11.10.0.1.0.0.105.744.9j1.10.0...0.0...1ac.1.12.igoogle.aUBaiHy_bHU)" turns up about 14 million hits; I'd say it's common usage, and far from a 'bad fit'

Comment: @Gnawme Correlation does not imply connotation.

Answer (score 5):

The words I most often see used to describe this phenomenon have been mentioned in the body of other answers, but not actually suggested as answers!

I'm including some examples found with the help of Google:

***embrace***

- *Over our 23 year history, Outright Vermont has intentionally explored and then **embraced** the use of the word “queer” as a term used by our youth population.*
- *Organizations that have **embraced** the word “queer” in their titles are not holding the standard higher, but instead have done a backslide into murky waters of ambiguity.*
- *While formerly negative words with reference to sexuality such as 'fag' and 'dyke' have been **embraced** within certain cultures ...*

***reclaim***

- *I was also asked about the protesters’ use of the word “slut” and whether or not feminists can **reclaim** that word and use it on their own terms. Here’s what was said:*
- *“Some people still see them as derogatory, but the words 'bitch' and 'slut' I think can be considered **reclaimed**,” Handler said.*
- *On the other hand, the word nigger has been “**reclaimed**” by black youths*

The difference seems to be that *embrace* means accepting the word as it is with its negative meanings whereas *reclaim* means that the new positive meaning has replaced the older negative meanings to some degree.

Comment: "reclaim" implies that one claimed it in the first place.

"embrace" works, thanks